# Is there some way to not use LiquidBase at all if you are using JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

I have tried the no-liquidbase profile, I have even tried removing the LiquidBase configuration and dependencies altogether, the code still attempts to create the DatabaseChangeLogLock table no matter what I do. Liquidbase comes along the moment I create any project using SQL databases.

Comment: Are you just misspelling liquibase? Give a [mre] to show *how* you did those things and what problem this is causing (for that matter, why you want to remove it to begin with).

Comment: Profile is no-liquibase without 'd' as suggested by @jonrsharpe, see https://www.jhipster.tech/profiles/#spring-profiles-switches

Comment: Spelling, and silent failures, together make a perfect failure... thank you...